# ELSE condition is not working in the while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","id6755695_artemi8","sharanod"
    ,"id6755695_user_info");
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $department = $_POST["department"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $sem = $_POST["semester"];
    $reg = $_POST["regulation"];

    $sql = "SELECT  book_name, author, edition, image FROM dept_search WHERE 
    department='$department' AND year='$year' AND semester='$sem' AND 
    regulations='$reg' ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if($row)
        {
            echo "<br>";
        ?>
        <img src=" <?php echo $row['image']; ?> " height="300" width="300">

        <?php
        echo "<br>";

        echo "<b>",$row['book_name'],"</b>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['author'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['edition'];

        }
        else
        {
            echo "sorry book not found";
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

please help me with this code,i am building a library management system.. The thing is I should be able to display the books if the given values are present i have in the database if not book not found must be displayed but in while loop after if, else does not runs.....

Comment: Your while loop will be exited as soon as the result set is fully traversed

Comment: it's normal $row was always true because $row always have value and exists

Comment: What is check condition inside while loop ?

Comment: You does to make your test before your loop

Comment: $row wil only be false when either the sql statement is invalid or there are no results on the query. So I guess you always have results coming back from the database, hence $row is always true.

What I do, is first check the $rows then do the loop (foreach or while)

Comment: `while($row = ` means the same as `if($row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your `else` statement will never run. If you are already inside the `while` loop, you will certainly have `$row` defined and for that reason, else will never run.

What you **can do** is, check beforehand if the query returned actual results, like so:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "<br>";
      ?>
      <img src=" <?php echo $row['image']; ?> " height="300" width="300">
      <?php
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<b>",$row['book_name'],"</b>";
      echo "<br>";
      echo $row['author'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo $row['edition'];
  }
}else{
    echo "Sorry book not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all the rows returned from the "mysqli_fetch..." command. Your "if" and "else" is useless -- you will always have rows. If you get no rows, you do not even enter the body of the while loop.

You need to COUNT the rows returned (count($row)) and display a message that nothing was found if the count is less than one.

Comment: Not sure about *nothing was found if the count is less than zero*, do you mean equal to 0?

Comment: @Nigel: I meant to type "one", but you are correct -- equals to zero would have worked just as well. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with mysqli_num_rows .. sample code as follows :

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($conn,$sql);
if($rowcount!=0){
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    echo "<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is that you have to change if the condition from `if($row)` to `if($other_condition)`

Currently, you are just checking either there is something inside `$row`, and this condition will never be wrong unless you will assign it `null`. Because where `$row` will have something then while loop will be executed, and when while loop will be executed then if condition will be executed.

you have to simply one thing, that is to change if condition like given below...

`if($row['value'] == 'something')`